# Msconfig -> Boot.ini -> Advanced Options -> Number of Processors

Tags: cpu, msconfig

Are these the number of the processors used for boot time or the cpu cores? Also, what's the default value and what would happen if I activate the max number of processors on the drop down list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default is the box Unchecked (means use all processors and threads), nothing bad will happen if you change it.

I have read post on both sides of this question, some say using all will boot faster, some say no. All I can say is try it for yourself and form your own opinion about boot performance based on your findings and hardware configuration.

http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/1770-increase-boot-up-speed-change-number-processors-used-boot-up-windows-7-a.html

Edit:

Conclusion: In Vista and W7 it uses all cores by default to boot and run, so this setting is more for disabling cores/processors not only at boot time, but disabled period.

I can detect no difference if i tick the box and set it to four, compared to the box being unticked.

If you experiment and need To restore all processors and threads, uncheck the box and reboot.

Here is a screenshot of the taskmanager with "number of processors" the tickbox unchecked, it shows all four cores as it should for my processor.

.
[image]

.

Now I set it to 2 processors and rebooted, (did not notice a significant difference in boot time)

.
[image]
.

Taskman now show only 2 cores operational

.
[image]

Comment: Check my edit....

Comment: I'm super confused now. Could you write the processor or processors you're using on your computer for that test?

Comment: Its a Intel core i5, it has two cores and each core has hyperthreading, so it will show 4 total for my particular processor.

Comment: You never stated your OS, I am using windows 7.

Comment: I have 7 too. So, Windows 7 interprets cores as processors huh? I have to test this now that I'm at home. Thanks Moab.

Comment: Yeah, I was able to boot my amd c-50 with one core at 1Ghz, I'm oficially in the 90's.

Comment: @questionbot, cores and hyperthreading are interpreted as individual processors by task manager.